# Norse like mapping software with input

Tags: maps

I am looking for a software similar to the [Norse attack map](http://map.norsecorp.com/#/) to give a visual representation of software deployments. Preferably, this software will take time and location as input and display an arrow, line, ping, etc. to a location on a **U.S.** map.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Python](http://www.python.org) has a plethora of charting tools including the capability of plotting to maps:

- [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) + [mpl_toolkits.basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) - Offline on your local machine, requires some learning to code python, *if you can't already*, but the examples in the gallery are a good starting point and only a few lines each.
- [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/) - Online, includes a grid, *spreadsheet like*, interface as well as APIs for python, R, MATLAB & JavaScript and interfaces to Excel, Scada, Julia, etc. **but** the map type charts are only avialble with the Pro, *charged for*, subscription.
- [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) - Both online and on your machine, recently added geo data mapping so still a work in progress to some extent. Requires python coding but less than matplotlib and has a number of very good and compact examples.

It is also well worth taking a look at [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) which allows you to produce maps from various data sources, in multiple layers, including adding your own data in point or line layers without having to know any programming.

Plot.ly has a free plan, which excludes the mapping, and a number of paid plans which I personally consider reasonably priced.
All of the other tools are free, gratis & open source.
All of the tools are available to work on multiple platforms including Windows, Linux & OS-X.

Comment: No offense, Steve, but what if the OP can't code?

Comment: @Mawg plot.ly has an excel like interface option as well as a python API but the mapping options are a pro only feature answer extended to address.